# Buttons in Outlook 2007, 2010, 2013 and 2016

Tags: html, outlook, html-email, outlook-2010, outlook-2007

I am getting this stroke inside of the button for a email I'm coding. It only appears in Outlook 2007, 2010, and 2013 and I can't figure out how to remove it? Any ideas?

[image]

Code:

```
`<a href="http://buttons.cm" style="color: #ffffff; background: #a52023; 
 border: 1px solid #a52023;  display: inline-block; font-family: tahoma;
 font-weight: 900; letter-spacing: 2px; font-size: 16px; border-radius: 80px;
 line-height: 60px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; width: 275px;
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; mso-hide: all;">GET FREE WORKWEAR</a>`
```

Comment: can you add the rest of your code aroudn this button? Please also note that the "mso-hide:all; css will actually make this a tag hidden in most Outlook versions, so this may not actually be the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yea, Windows Outlook 2007, 2010, 2013, and even 2016 all have spotty support for the box model. To get a nice-looking, clickable button working (unfortunately) requires a lot more code.

Might need to play with the border thickness, padding, and number of `&nbsp;`s, but this should solve your issue and give you a decent-looking, working button across all email clients (including Outlook):

```
<!-- Button : Begin -->
<table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="margin: auto;">
    <tr>
        <td style="border-radius: 3px; background: #a52023; text-align: center;">
            <a href="http://www.google.com" style="background: #a52023; border: 15px solid #a52023; font-family: tahoma; font-weight: 900; letter-spacing: 2px; font-size: 16px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 60px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: 900; text-transform: uppercase;">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color:#ffffff">Get Free Workwear</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- Button : END -->
```

Answer (score 6):

That works in outlook (source: https://gist.github.com/benknight/3316487) :

```
<span style="display: inline-block; text-align: center; background-color: #d21d00; border: 1px solid #5d150e; color: white;">
  <span style="display: inline-block; background-color: #d21d00; color: white; border-width: 1px 0 0 1px; border-color: #f3948a; border-style: solid;">
    <a style="display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; color: white; border-color: #d21d00; border-width: 5px 10px; border-style: solid; white-space: nowrap;" href="https://stackoverflow.com">Go to Stackoverflow</a>
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Works with Outlook 365